# Expand a inner list into a flat list

Tags: python

I have a list of list (***var_list***) that I want to "expand" into a *flat* list (***list1***), see bellow:

```
environment = {
    "KEY1": "VALUE1",
    "KEY2": "VALUE2",
}

var_list = [
    ["var", f"{key}={value}"] for key, value in environment.items()
]

list1 = ["foo", "bar"]

result = list1.extend(var_list)

# PS. Must be a list, not a `' '.join`

print(f"{result=}") # None.

print(result == ["foo", "bar", "var", "KEY1=KEY1", "var", "KEY2=KEY2"]) # returns False. Should be True or equal
```

How can I do this in python, without using `' '.join`?

Comment: No. This is not the problem.

Comment: @Skhaz: you must admit that `result = list1.extend(...` is *part* of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I can use `operator.concat`

```
list1 = ["foo", "bar"] + functools.reduce(operator.concat, var_list)
```

Comment: Surely now `print(f"{result=}") ` will fail.

Comment: There's an error is line `result = list1.extend(var_list)`, because the extend method changes the `list1` itself and returns None.

So, you don't need a `result` list.